# How to force 'always' location access in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

The app that I'm building needs always location access to work properly. The app basically tracks location and puts it on a map and stuff (details not important, lol).

My goal is this:

1. Prompt user to enable "always" location access
2. If always location access has been requested but the user said no, make the app unusable - basically just show a little button that redirects them to settings where they can change that setting.

My AppDelegate.swift is implementing CLLocationManagerDelegate, and the code is as follows:

```
alreadyRequestedLocationWhenInUse = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "alreadyRequestedLocationWhenInUse")
alreadyRequestedLocationAlways = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "alreadyRequestedLocationAlways")

        func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
      
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            if (!alreadyRequestedLocationWhenInUse) {
                print("Requesting location access 'while in use'.")
                self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadyRequestedLocationWhenInUse")
                alreadyRequestedLocationWhenInUse = true
            } else {
                promptToChangeLocationSettings()
            }
        case .restricted, .denied:
            print("No Location access")
            promptToChangeLocationSettings()
            break;
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            if (!alreadyRequestedLocationAlways) {
                print("Requesting location access 'Always'.")
                self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadyRequestedLocationAlways")
                alreadyRequestedLocationAlways = true
            } else {
                promptToChangeLocationSettings()
            }
            break;
        case .authorizedAlways:
            self.startLocationMonitoring();
            break;
        default:
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
            return
        }
    }
```

where promptToChangeLocationSettings() is a properly working function that takes the user to the settings page for my app.

The problem is that the user isn't prompted to enable "Always location tracking" until they exit the app and come back. They are asked for 'while in use' permissions (and I know that the way it works is they have to say yes to that first), but I want the always prompt to happen right away! In theory, the locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization function should be called AGAIN after the 'while use' authorization is granted, but this does not happen! Why does this not happen? Instead, promptUserToChangeLocationSettings() runs and makes the app unusable BEFORE the user gets the little poup that asks whether they want to enable 'always' location access.

Can someone help me fix this?
By the way, I am using UserDefaults to keep track of whether we have done a location permission request (as the request can only be done once).

Comment: I would adopt a different approach. Ask for "when in use" then display an information explaining why you need "always" and then when they dismiss that screen, ask for always. You should also consider carefully whether "when in use" with background location will be sufficient and you also need to consider the impact of imprecise location in iOS 14.

Comment: Two options: 1. You can ask for when-in-use, and after they grant it, then request always in the authorization status changed delegate method. That will trigger 2nd prompt immediately (but in iOS 13.4 and later, only; e.g. in 13.0, you won’t see this second alert). 2. Ask for always, get provisional always (use sees when-in-use, authorization status as seen by app if authorizeAlways). Then when the app actually exercises it’s “always powers”, the user will see second prompt for upgrade-when-in-use-to-always at that a time of the OS’s choosing. Those are the two options in iOS 13.4 and later.

Comment: @Rob, isn't option 1 what they are already doing?  Perhaps they aren't testing on iOS 13.4 or later.

Comment: I was just trying to outline the options (and make the iOS version requirement explicit).

Comment: By the way, kuinsiho, the `break` and `return` statements and the semicolons are not required/recommended in Swift.

Comment: I'd also suggest removing the `UserDefaults` logic. The user can change location permissions in the Settings app, so it doesn't matter what you asked for before. Just use the `authorizationStatus`.

Comment: Hey @Rob, thanks! For the userdefaults, if authStatus is 'denied' I will redirect them to the settings page, but if it is 'while in use', I have to redirect to the settings page or request always authorization if it has not been done yet, so that's why I need the userdefaults.

Comment: Also @Rob: For the option 1 you have mentioned above, I am doing exactly what you are saying, and it does not prompt the user to change to "always' even upon leaving the app (putting the app in the background). I immediately see the prompt to proceed to settings. If I change up the code, the always location access permission request only happens when I close the app fully and then reopen and then I get the "always' prompt. I have an iPhone SE running iOS 13.6 so I don't quite get why this is happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few observations about this flow where we request “when in use” first, and when that's granted, only then request “always” (as discussed in WWDC 2020 [What's New in Location](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10660/?time=1274)):

1. Make sure you run this on a device, not the simulator. You may not see the subsequent “upgrade ‘when-in-use’ to ‘always’” permission alert when using a simulator.
2. This feature was introduced in iOS 13.4. Make sure you are not attempting this on an earlier iOS 13 version. On those earlier versions, you won’t see the second alert to upgrade to “always”.
3. Make sure you don’t have a lingering `requestAlwaysAuthorization` elsewhere in your code-base that might have put the app in a “provisional always” state. Once in provisional state, you are locked into the provisional flow of 13.0.

---

I know it isn’t what you’re looking for, but for the sake of future readers, the alternative to the above is the simpler “provisional always” flow introduced in iOS 13.0 (outlined in WWDC 2019's [What's New in Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/?time=103)). You just call `requestAlwaysAuthorization` (never calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`). Apple's intent here was to let the user better reason about what’s going on, showing the “when in use” alert while the app is in use and automatically showing the “always” upgrade alert when location services are used while the app isn't running.

Comment: The simulator with iOS 16 now shows the subsequent requests of `when-in-use` and `always-allow`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that got the result I desired:
Firstly: Make a call to locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(locationManager) in the AppDelegate.swift didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function. I also called it in applicationWillEnterForeground just so that it rechecks every time the app opens.

Secondly, this is my new locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization function. Just need to remove the return/break statements, but I'm just gonna answer this now before I forget:

```
func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
  
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .notDetermined:
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "alreadyRequestedAlwaysLocationAccess")
        alreadyRequestedAlwaysLocationAccess = false
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.coreLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            self.locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(manager)
        }
        break;
    case .restricted, .denied:
        print("No Location access")
        promptToChangeLocationSettings()
        break;
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        if (!alreadyRequestedAlwaysLocationAccess) {
            print("Requesting location access 'Always'.")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadyRequestedAlwaysLocationAccess")
            alreadyRequestedAlwaysLocationAccess = true

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.coreLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                self.locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(manager)
            }
        } else {
            promptToChangeLocationSettings()
        }
        break;
    case .authorizedAlways:
        self.startLocationMonitoring();
        break;
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m glad you solved this. Generally you shouldn’t have to manually call this, though. When you set the delegate it should be called automatically. Maybe your location manager was a global or a static (both of which instantiate it lazily) or explicitly marked it as a `lazy` var?

Comment: @Rob - My location manager is global (declared as var locationManager : CLLocationManager in AppDelegate, outside any functions) and then initialized with  CLLocationManager.init(). Totally did not realize that this could be a cause of the issue!

Comment: “Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a similar manner to Lazy Stored Properties. Unlike lazy stored properties, global constants and variables do not need to be marked with the lazy modifier.” https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID263